# If $\| M\|$ denotes the norm of the matrix $M$, does the inequality $M b\cdot c \le \|M\| |c|$ hold true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $A\in M_{3\times 3}$ and $b, c\in\mathbb{R}^3$ be two nonnull vectors with $|b|\le 1$.
Consider the dot product

$$ Mb\cdot c.$$

I would like to know if my following argument is valid.

As $Mb$ is a vector, then
$$ M b\cdot c \le |M\cdot b| |c|\le \|M\| |c|,$$

where $\|M\|$ denotes the matrix-norm of $M$ and I used the assumption $|b|\le 1$.

Do you think my argument is valid?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first inequality $Mb\cdot c\leq|Mb||c|$ is known as Cauchy Schwartz and the second inequality $|Mb||c|\leq\|M\||b||c|$ follows from the definition of operator norm so your argument is valid, provided you use the operator norm as your matrix norm. (Turns our there are [many many matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm)).